# Does enabling pg_stat_statements reduce disk space?

Tags: postgresql

Recently I was informed that since enabling `pg_stat_statements`, the available disk space is dropping fast. I don't think it's caused by that, but I wonder: Does enabling `pg_stat_statements` reduce disk space? And by how much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pg_stat_statements` shouldn't use much disk space.

It uses two files:

- `pg_stat_statements.stat` persists `pg_stat_statement`'s data across server restarts.

  It is written upon shutdown and read on server startup. The file is deleted as soon as it has been read, so it should not be present when the server is up.
- `pg_stat_tmp/pgss_query_texts.stat` contains the text of the queries being tracked.

  This file will grow as new statements are added, but if it becomes too big, `pg_stat_statements` will perform a “garbage collection” and rewrite it.

If you suspect that there is a disk space problem with `pg_stat_statements`, check `pg_stat_tmp/pgss_query_texts.stat`. But I don't think this file can be a problem unless you set `pg_stat_statements.max` to an astronomically high value and run lots of different statements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One more question: What about database size after enabling pg_stat_statements? Does the database increase significantly?

Comment: The database size (as measured with `pg_database_size`) shouldn't increase at all.

Comment: ok, good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ... since enabling pg_stat_statements, the available disk space is dropping.

So pg_stat_statements is consuming disk space.
*This is to be expected*, since it's purpose is to collect (and store) statistics about every single query that passes through your Postgres cluster.  All that data has to be stored somewhere and that will take up space.  Not a lot, compared to your database as a whole, I suspect, but some.

You should monitor it for a while and adjust your Capacity Plans accordingly.

Comment: `pg_stat_statement` only tracks a maximum number of statements (`pg_stat_statements.max`), and garbage is collected whenever the file size exceeds a limit based on that value. How can it consume much disk space?